# Redirect button woocommerce to another page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to redirect the validate order button in the woocommerce plugin to another page that I created myself without modifying the code of the woocommerce plugin.
I work with elementor

Comment: The etiquette here requires you to show what research you did on finding a solution. Even better, post a possible solution that you created and explain what's not working.